# Capybara Webkit + Braintree—"Unable to locate frame"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, iframe, braintree, braintree-rails

I'm trying to access Braintree's hosted fields with the following code:

```
within_frame('braintree-hosted-field-number') do
  fill_in 'Credit card number', with: '4111-1111-1111-1111'
end
```

The frame's name is correct, I copied it from the `inspect` panel on Chrome.
But I get this error

```
Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:
   Unable to locate frame.
```

What am I doing wrong? Or, more importantly, how do I debug this/see what's going on?

---

### Edit

Here is my code, as requested. Note that the whole system works fine if I go through and manually fill out the fields and submit the form.

**Slim**

```
= f.fields_for :user do |u|
    .control-group.col-24.payment-details
      label.half
        .field-title First Name
        = u.text_field :first_name
      label.half
        .field-title Last Name
        = u.text_field :last_name
      label.full
        .field-title Email for receipt
        = u.email_field :email
      label.full
        .field-title Credit card number
        .bt-field#credit-card
      label.half
        .field-title Expiry date
        .bt-field#exp-card
      label.half
        .field-title CVC
        .bt-field#cvv-card

script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.24.0.min.js"
```

**CoffeeScript**

```
braintree.setup(clientToken, "custom", {
          id: "donate-form",
          onPaymentMethodReceived: (obj)->
            formdata = donationForm.getFormData()
            formdata.set "payment_method_nonce", obj.nonce
            donationForm.send(formdata)
          onError: (obj)->
            errors = []
            switch obj.type
              when "VALIDATION"
                errors.push "Invalid payment details. Please correct your payment details."
              else
                errors.push "Something went wrong. Please check your payment details and try again."
            donationForm.printErrors("donation-errors", errors)
          hostedFields: {
            styles: {
            "input": {
              "font-size": "14px",
              "font-weight": "bold",
              "font-family": "Lato, Helvetica, Arial, Geneva, sans-serif",
              "color": "#464646;",
              "transition": colorTransition,
              "-webkit-transition": colorTransition
              },
            ".invalid": { color: "#DD0000"} },
            number: {selector: "#credit-card"},
            cvv: {selector: "#cvv-card"},
            expirationDate: {selector: "#exp-card", "placeholder": "dd/mm"}
          }
        })
```

### Edit 2

**donation_module_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Donation Module", type: :feature do

  scenario "Wrong public token" do
    visit "/donate?t=BAD_URL&frame=1"
    expect(page).to have_content("Are you sure you're installing this on the correct website?")
  end

  scenario "Public visitor creates a new donation", driver: :webkit do

    #load page
    website = create(:website)
    page.driver.header 'Referer', website.website
    visit "/donate?t=#{website.public_token}&frame=1"

    #verify page 1 loaded
    expect(page).not_to have_content("Are you sure you're installing this on the correct website?")

    #fill page 1
    find("input[value='20'] ~ div").click

    #go to page 2
    find("#credit-details").click

    #verify page 2 content is loaded
    expect(find(".total-cost-text")).to be_visible

    #fill page 2
    fill_in 'First Name', with: 'Leeroy'
    fill_in 'Last Name', with: 'Jenkins'
    fill_in 'Email for receipt', with: 'new_donor@email.com'

    sleep 5
    within_frame('braintree-hosted-field-number') do
      fill_in 'Credit card number', with: '4111-1111-1111-1111'
    end

    within_frame('#braintree-hosted-field-expirationDate') do
      fill_in '#expiration', with: '09/19'
    end

    within_frame('#braintree-hosted-field-cvv') do
      fill_in '#cvv', with: '123'
    end
    find('Make payment').click


    # expect to make a new user, new donation, new receipt, emailed receipt
  end
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**
Modified to show only the related parts:

```
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.allow_url("js.braintreegateway.com")
  config.allow_url("fonts.googleapis.com")
  config.allow_unknown_urls
  config.debug = true
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML and JavaScript you're using to set up Hosted Fields?

Comment: Done, but note that the system works when I go through manually, it only breaks if I'm trying to use capybara.

Comment: It looks like you might be using the wrong name for your credit card number field in `fill_in`. Have you tried "Credit Card Number" or "credit-card-number"?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's right, but I can't even test that because the code breaks at  `within_frame`

Comment: I'm able to get this working just fine, my guess is that the javascript isn't loading. 

Would you be able to include some of the configuration, such as anything in the spec helper that could be relevant? Also just to be sure, you have `:type => feature` and `:js => true` correct?

Comment: I use `driver: :webkit` which I understand replaces the need for `js: true`

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

I don't have an answer for you as to why this might be happening, copying your setup I'm able to get it to work. I do have a couple of additional thoughts that may help.

1) Take a look at the debug output (looks like you already have this enabled with `config.debug = true`) and make sure there are no errors. Here are the relevant parts of my output -

```
"Visit(http:/localhost:3000/hostedfields_payment)" started page load 
Started request to "http://localhost:3000/hostedfields_payment" 
Finished "Visit(http:/localhost:3000/hostedfields_payment)" with response "Success()" 
Started request to "https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.17.5.js" 
Started request to "https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/-/client_api/v1/configuration?-
Received 200 from "https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/-/client_api/v1/configuration?- 
Received "FrameFocus(braintree-hosted-field-number)" 
Load started 
Started request to "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/hosted-fields/2.17.5/hosted-fields-frame.html#91586a91-c55f-4e51-80e6-7cd750f9c750" 
Started request to "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/hosted-fields/2.17.5/hosted-fields-frame.html#91586a91-c55f-4e51-80e6-7cd750f9c750" 
Started request to "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/hosted-fields/2.17.5/hosted-fields-frame.html#91586a91-c55f-4e51-80e6-7cd750f9c750" 
"TimeoutCommand" waiting for load to finish  
Started request to "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/hosted-fields/2.17.5/braintree-hosted-fields-internal.min.js" 
Received 200 from "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/hosted-fields/2.17.5/hosted-fields-frame.html#91586a91-c55f-4e51-80e6-7cd750f9c750" 
Received 200 from "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/hosted-fields/2.17.5/hosted-fields-frame.html#91586a91-c55f-4e51-80e6-7cd750f9c750" 
Received 200 from "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/hosted-fields/2.17.5/hosted-fields-frame.html#91586a91-c55f-4e51-80e6-7cd750f9c750" 
Received 200 from "https://assets.braintreegateway.com/hosted-fields/2.17.5/braintree-hosted-fields-internal.min.js" 
Page finished with true 
Load finished 
Started "FrameFocus(braintree-hosted-field-number)"
Finished "FrameFocus(braintree-hosted-field-number)" with response "Success()" 
Wrote response true "" 
Received "FindCss(input#credit-card-number)" 
Started "FindCss(input#credit-card-number)" 
Finished "FindCss(input#credit-card-number)" with response "Success()"
```

2) A gnarly way you could check is at the end your `sleep 5`, print the body to a file and open it up. You can check that the iframes exist.

```
File.open("looking_for_iframes.html", "w") do |file|
  file.print(page.body)
end
```

Otherwise feel free to reach out to [Braintree Support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).